# Generate one PDF using multiple FO objects using apache fop in java

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

Can anyone suggest me how to create one pdf using multiple Apache fo objects?

We know that Apache fop generates pdf using FO(formatting objects). FO is created from xml by applying xsl.

My requirement is, I will be generating multi page pdf files. Each page template will be different, so I would need multiple xml and xsl files for one pdf. I thought of merging them and creating one FO but some PDF size would go till 2000 pages which leads to `OutOfMemoryError`.

I went through the Apache FOP reference example files for creating one pdf using multiple fop but I could not find one.

Comment: 2000 pages isn't that large and isn't beyond the capabilities of FOP. Your JVM memory setting may just be too low.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Also, I would like to know if there is a way to generate a pdf using multiple FO objects. As I mentioned that templates would be different for each page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An FO file you can contain as many `fo:page-sequence` elements as you want** or need, each one with its `master-reference` property pointing to a page master.

So, you can have a single FO file with

- several `fo:page-sequence` elements with the **same** page layout (think of the different chapters in a book)
- several `fo:page-sequence` each one with a **different** layout
- a combination of the previous cases

Besides, FOP processes the content of each page `fo:page-sequence` independently, so having many smaller page sequences instead of a giant one (if possible) also helps avoiding out-of-memory errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have defined a table in one page sequence but the table itself goes through several hundreds of pages. As FOP starts rendering only when it reaches end of page sequences it is consuming lots of heap memory. Is there any way to split this?                                                         Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.